# PHP - (very) long loading with fopen

Tags: php, fopen

When using the fopen handle, loading times become drastically huge. About 10 seconds or so to be precise.

```
$handle = fopen("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player={$pname}", "r");
if (FALSE === $handle) {
echo "Failed";
    exit("Failed to open stream to URL");
}

$contents = '';

while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents .= fread($handle, 32);
}
```

Above is the code I am using.
Is this an inefficient way to do it? If so, what is the efficient way?

I also explode these results and print them. But even after removing the printing of the results part, the load times are unchanged.

Comment: How big is the file your are opening : ko, Mo, Go ?

Comment: @Loufylouf It's a webpage with very plain, simple data. This: http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=xmax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can speed it up if you use some other way to do the http request.

You can use cURL:

```
 $url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player={$pname}";
 $c = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 $contents = curl_exec($c);
 curl_close($c);
```

Or try it via:

```
$contents = file_get_contents( "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player={$pname}" );
```

Comment: Second option provided the same result with loading times. However, the first one was excellent. Instantly cut out all the ridiculous loading times. Thank you.